# Protection IC stopping battery from charging

Tags: charger, lipo, over-voltage-protection

I'm using an [AP9101C](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP9101C.pdf) as a protection IC and an [MCP73811](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22036b.pdf) as a charger IC for a single cell Li-po like this:

[image]

The load works fine, but when I connect +VDC (5 V), suddenly CO of the AP9101C goes to 0 preventing the battery from charging and showing 4.2 V on +BATT to GND and 3.6 V on the battery itself (0.8 V forward on diode of Q4 or 5).

If I short Q5, the battery charges normally and CO even goes high, but when I remove the short, it stops again.

If I would connect VSS of the charger IC to -BATT, I would bypass Q5 (and the overcharge protection), but the datasheet of the charge IC specifies to connect charger +Batt and Q5 as I did.

Adding diodes to Q5 (and Q6) will not help, I think, because it would still cause a forward voltage.

Anyway, what am I doing wrong and how should I fix this? Or can't these two ICs work together?

Any help is highly appreciated, I'm really stuck.

Added a screenshot of the wireless reciever with another capacitor to GND, but this one is a good 5 cm away from IC2 and parallel to the induction coil, so I guess I do need that C4 connected properly:

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of C4?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott From the datasheet, C4 is placed between VDD and VSS of IC2 to stabilise the power supply (filtering). I know it's connected wrong, but it should not matter because there are more capacitors from +VDC to GND and when i disconnect C4 it still doesnt work.

Comment: There are no other capacitors between VDD and GND in your schematic. To be fully effective C4 should be placed directly across the pins of the IC. Perhaps this improper bypassing is part of your EMI problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the wireless charger supplying the 5 V (not in the screenshot) that induced a voltage which made the IC think the battery was fully charged. When I keep a little more distance, the board works normally. Who would have thought. I also added some more info about the wireless receiver. Thanks to Bruce Abbott, I see it might be C4 that is connected wrong.

Comment: Wireless charging works by eletromagnetic induction, so *all* low-impedance loops in the circuit are potential victims. I bet you that the node that was affected was a part of a low-impedance loop. Note that some loops become low-impedance when e.g. input protection or parasitic diodes get polarized into condution.